# Persist recording while audio is playing in another app

Tags: ios, react-native, audio, text-to-speech, record

Like the title says, how can I continue recording in the background to capture the audio of another app? It'll need to transcribe the audio in real time, so I've elected to use [`react-native-voice`](https://github.com/react-native-voice/voice/tree/master) which allows for just that.

Right now, I'm able to get the app to record in the background, but it stops whenever audio from another app starts playing. If it helps, I need this to work on iOS.

I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.